# How do i know how much data is stored in my Elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to know how much data is stored in my Elastic search.

I m exploring the cluster-stats API.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/cluster-stats.html
Does "store" -> size_in_bytes , show the size of data stored ?

Answer (score 1):

yes, using Cluster stats API, `size_in_bytes` in 'store' represents the total size, in bytes, of all shards assigned to selected nodes.

Statistics can be also returned in a format suitable for humans adding `human=true` in the request, for example:

```
http://localhost:9200/_cluster/stats?human=true
```

```
"store": {
            "size": "93.7mb",
            "size_in_bytes": 98292482,
            "total_data_set_size": "93.7mb",
            "total_data_set_size_in_bytes": 98292482,
            "reserved": "0b",
            "reserved_in_bytes": 0
        },
```

You can also use [cat allocation API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-allocation.html) to get used and available disk space for each node and disk space used by the node’s shards (`disk.indices`):

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v
```

If you are interested in knowing the store size **for each index** in a cluster, you can use the [cat indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.6/cat-indices.html#cat-indices):

```
http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v
```